# Why ReSharper tries to run all my tests twice, one for .NET 5 then one for .NET 6?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, .net-5, .net-6.0

**Context**

I've recently upgraded my solution from .NET 5 to .NET 6. Basically nothing changed so far, except the `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>` changed to `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` and of course I've updated all packages to the latest release versions.

Since then, when I run my unit tests (NUnit) with ReSharper runner ReSharper displays all my tests twice, one for .NET 5 then one for .NET 6, and for the .NET 5 versions flagged as "not supported". I am not asking why those are not supported (full .NET 5 SDK is installed, not talking about that, a half days ago the full solutions was .NET and compiled, run, and tested correctly.

The .NET 6 tests are running btw and all OK with them, but the duplicated "not supported" nodes pollute the result.

**Question**

Why ReSharper tries to deal with this two versions of unit tests, and where can I configure to only run test .NET 6?

[image]

Why ReSharper tries to run all my tests twice, one for .NET 5 then one for .NET 6?

Comment: What version of ReSharper are you using? Try installing EAP. Also have you tried cleaning ReSharper caches?

Comment: This is the latest EAP, dec, 2021. It works perfectly with VS 2022, and .NET 6 as the OP states, but somehow has this weird test case duplication issue, for .NET 5

Comment: I had a similar issue. Closing the Solution and deleting all `bin` and `obj` folders solved it for me

Comment: me too............